# In tradingview, pine script function strategy.exit doesn't work if take profit and stop loss were set separately instead of a single line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

The following code works for me when I try to set the stop loss and take profit level:

```
strategy.exit("TP/SL 1", "Long Entry 1",  stop = long_stop_level,  limit = long_profit_level)
```

But the issue for this code is that it will not tell me it is a stop loss exit or take profit exit.. so I tried to split it off to the following manner:

```
strategy.exit("SL 1", "Long Entry 1",  stop = long_stop_level)
strategy.exit("TP 1", "Long Entry 1",  limit = long_profit_level)
```

But I notice that only the stop loss is working but not the take profit, is there anyway I could fix that?

Comment: Short answer, no. What do you need it split for?

Comment: So that I can know what cause the strategy to exit, in the original code, it will only display "TP/SL 1" but does not tell me it hits the target profit or stop loss at all

Comment: I think the TV will can take care about such case.

Comment: @jguy FYI, TradingView added new comment parameters for the `strategy.exit()` function.
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this. and it will display on chart SL and TP. Note that i'm using v5

```
strategy.exit("exit Long", from_entry="Long",loss= sl,profit = tp,comment_profit="Buy TP", comment_loss="Buy SL")
```